# Change Bitlocker to use the TPM plus a USB key and a PIN

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I have bitlocker running on Windows 7 (x86) on a Dell D630 laptop (it has a 1.2 TPM).

It is running in transparent mode.

I'd like to know how to configure it to use a PIN and a USB key as well, but I can't find anything that looks like it does this in the UI.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Do I have to remove bitlocker and re-enable it??

(This should be possible according to this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker_Drive_Encryption)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Matthias Hamann [here](http://www.caesarcipher.com/2008/08/30/bitlocker-drive-encryption-tpm-pin-usb-key-vista-sp1/):

> To the great relief of any paranoid
>   encryption junkie, Microsoft decided
>   to add another mode, which requires
>   TPM + PIN + USB Key to start up your
>   computer. This feature was introduced
>   with Service Pack 1 for Vista and
>   makes it really hard for an attacker
>   to get hold of your authentication
>   details if you don’t write your PIN on
>   your USB stick or get “questioned” by
>   someone with a blow torch and a pair
>   of pliers.
>
> So how does it work? Well, although
>   there is no GUI option for this new
>   mode, it’s surprisingly simple to
>   activate:
>
> 1. Click on the Vista logo / start button.
> 2. Type cmd in the search box and do NOT hit enter.
> 3. Right-click on the command prompt item (cmd.exe) and select “Run as
>      administrator” from the context menu.
> 4. Enter `cscript manage-bde.wsf -on c: -rp -rk d: -tpsk -tp 1234567 -tsk
>      e:` and hit enter. (“c:” is the drive
>      which you want to encrypt / your OS
>      volume; “d:” is the drive where the
>      recovery key will be stored at;
>      “1234567” is your secret PIN, which
>      can consist of up to 20 digits; “e:”
>      is your USB key.)
> 5. Write down the recovery password and hide it at a SAFE location (e.g.,
>      under your keyboard  ).
> 6. Type exit and hit enter.
> 7. DONE!