# Bitlocker activated on win 8 with USB Key, want to switch to pin

Tags: windows, windows-8, security, bitlocker

I'm having trouble figuring out how to switch from USB key to pin unlock for my bitlocker protection on my tablet for work. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Bitlocker to use the TPM plus a USB key and a PIN](http://superuser.com/questions/116080/change-bitlocker-to-use-the-tpm-plus-a-usb-key-and-a-pin)

Comment: I can't have a USB drive to unlock my device as it is not a personal device and will be sent out to another facility. I need to remove the USB Key unlock and replace it with a pin unlock for Bitlocker. @Ramhound

Comment: You will need to be `Administrator` of your domain to do [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/55394/how-do-i-set-the-bitlocker-pin) if you are not a domain `Administrator` get one to do it.  Of course based on [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-is-a-BitLocker-Drive-Encryption-startup-key-or-PIN) it seems to indicate the start-up key will still be required.

Comment: I have Administrator rights on my domain, Bitlocker is currently using a USB Key to unlock the drive. I want to have the device require a pin at startup to unlock the device. I have both the USB key and rights to change the settings, I am just unaware of how to do so once the drive has been locked with the USB Key encryption method.

Comment: So there is no way to revert the changes to the drive? and remove the USB from the equation?

Comment: I definitely want a startup key to be used with the pin i choose, however I am not getting that option as I am backing up the key to a USB drive. Bitlocker management is not giving me the option once the drive is encrypted.

Comment: What I'm saying is because of my TPM settings it's backing up the key to my USB device. I want to remove all settings so that I can use a pin at startup which is the startup-pin, correct?

Comment: I've set these up before without a USB device plugged in on startup. I believe the TPM takes care of that. However the TPM settings on this device were already activated and I could not set it up with Bitlocker initially when I started the setup process.

Answer (score 0):

*Slow* but sure:

1. Turn off Bitlocker and decrypt the drive. See [Turning Off BitLocker Drive Encryption](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424315%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (directions are for Windows 7, but I presume the same for 8).
2. Re-encrypt the drive using password rather than USB ID.